# Python command line echo input

Tags: python, bash, command-line, echo

I want to use the command line in the following manner:
`$ echo "yada yada" | python3 file.py`

and the python file should use the string followed by echo as input. I have no idea how to approach this, but I assume I should use the sys module in some way?

Thanks on beforehand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5804732/15981783

Comment: There are [several ways](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/read-stdin-python) to do this.